# Vue component css being overwriten by bootstrapp-sass on Laravel

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a almost vanilla instalation of Laravel.
No matter what i do, all my scoped css inside the component is simply ignored and bootstrap-sass styles are applied instead.
[image: Example of this happening]

How can i stop this from rappening?

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the bootstrap.css file before the bundled webpack file.
2. Use clear selectors, because they are called in hierachy. Like inline, id, class... the more precise selector is used.

The following list of selector types increases by specificity: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types